# Foreach value from POST from form

Tags: php, post, while-loop

I post some data over to another page from a form. It's a shopping cart, and the form that's being submitted is being generated on the page before depending on how many items are in the cart. For example, if there's only 1 items then we only have the field name 'item_name_1' which should store a value like "Sticker" and 'item_price_1' which stores the price of that item. But if someone has 5 items, we would need 'item_name_2', 'item_name_3', etc. to get the values for each item up to the fifth one.

What would be the best way to loop through those items to get the values?

Here's what I have, which obviously isn't working.

```
extract($_POST);

$x = 1; // Assuming there's always one item we're on this page, we set the variable to get into the loop

while(${'item_name_' .$x} != '') {

echo ${'item_name' .$x};

$x++;

}
```

I'm still relatively new to this kind of usage, so I'm not entirely how the best way to deal with it.

Thanks.

Comment: This is unrelated to the question, but you should never used extract on $_POST as highlighted in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use array-like fields:

```
<input name="name_for_the_items[]"/>
```

You can loop through the fields:

```
foreach($_POST['name_for_the_items'] as $item)
{
  //do something with $item
}
```

Comment: This is working for me. Thank you. With that $item variable, how would I get the value of item_price as well inside the same loop? I want to be able to print the item_name, item_price and item_quantity for each item.

Comment: @scatterbomb: use names like `item[1][name]`,`item[1][price]`, `item[2][name]`, `item[2][price]`. `var_dump($_POST);` to see the result.

Comment: @Dr.Molle: what if I have multiple forms but want to submit values from different forms, post is returning only last form value

Comment: @logan: You cant submit multiple forms with a single request. You'll need to merge the forms before you submit them(can be done on clientside via javascript)

Comment: @Dr.Molle : I raised a query on processing multiple form POST values. Could you please answer it here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076695/php-to-process-dynamic-multiple-form-post-method-values/22076809

Answer (score 55):

First, please do not use extract(), it can be a security problem because it is easy to manipulate POST parameters

In addition, you don't have to use variable variable names (that sounds odd), instead:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  echo "POST parameter '$key' has '$value'";
}
```

To ensure that you have only parameters beginning with 'item_name' you can check it like so:

```
$param_name = 'item_name';
if(substr($key, 0, strlen($param_name)) == $param_name) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm leaning toward Dr.Molle's example, but I appreciate the heads up about extract(). I've removed it from my code.

Comment: I like the POST array more, too.

Comment: @Alp: what if I have multiple forms & wanted to submit values from different forms, post is returning only last form value

Comment: @logan: it's not possible to submit more than one form at the same time. But you could collect all data with Javascript and send a custom ajax request to the server. Or put everything in one form.

Comment: @Alp : I raised a query on processing multiple form POST values. Could you please answer it here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076695/php-to-process-dynamic-multiple-form-post-method-values/22076809

Answer (score 1):

If your post keys have to be parsed and the keys are sequences with data, you can try this:

Post data example: Storeitem|14=data14

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $key=Filterdata($key); $value=Filterdata($value);
    echo($key."=".$value."<br>");
}
```

then you can use strpos to isolate the end of the key separating the number from the key.

Answer (score 0):

i wouldn't do it this way

I'd use name arrays in the form elements

so i'd get the layout

```
$_POST['field'][0]['name'] = 'value';
$_POST['field'][0]['price'] = 'value';
$_POST['field'][1]['name'] = 'value';
$_POST['field'][1]['price'] = 'value';
```

then you could do an array slice to get the amount you need

Comment: If you have dozens of fields this is not efficient.