# PHP to process dynamic Multiple Form POST method values

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have jQuery to submit 'N' number of forms. Now I need to read the `POST` values based on the number of components. Can anyone suggest code to read those all `POST` values?
especially i want to read `approve1` , `approve2` `...` values

**Note:** when i click submit all these different form values are submitted to submit.php 
page

**My Form:**

```
<form name="f1" action="submit.php" method=POST>
<input type="hidden" name="approve1" value="93545" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit/>
</form>

<form name="f2" action="submit.php" method=POST>
<input type="hidden" name="approve2" value="93545" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit/>
</form>

.....

<input type="button" value="Submit All"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitAll").click(function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var newForm = $("<form action='submit.php' method='POST'></form>");
        $("form input[type='hidden']").each(function(i, e) {
            newForm.append(
                $("<input type='hidden' />")
                    .attr("name", e.name)
                    .attr("value", e.value)
            );
        });
        $(document.body).append(newForm);
        newForm.submit();
    });
});
```

`foreach($_POST as $name => $value)` posts only last form value `i.e approve2 value` in this example

Comment: Does the request made from JS really sends **approve1** and **approve2**? If so, you can access them via `$_POST['approve1']` and `$_POST['approve2']`

Comment: @MichalBrašna: Yes! I Can access it not a problem. But my problem is it can send `N approve` POST values. How should it find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
  // Here you have access to parameter names and their values
  echo "<p>name is $name and value is $value</p>";
}
```

Comment: i did a test. its not working.. There are 10 form values posted but this code is returning only th last form values. `foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
   echo $i."<br>";$i=$i+1;
}`

 outputs `only the last form values are returned`

Comment: @logan What is `$i`? I cannot see it in your code, or in what I suggested.

Comment: I just put it for testing purpose. to print how many values are posted.  consider only 2 forms are there in my question, for it , simply it returns `approve2` POST value only others are not coming. Where are i could see all POST values in `Chrome -> develoer -> network` area

Comment: @logan if you want to see **all** `post`ed names and their values, use the updated code. If you don't see what you expect, it simply means you do not post it.

Comment: updated code ? where is it ? And more over, i said, the JQuery submitting 2 post values from different forms. i could see it in developer section of chrome page. but when i use `foreach($_POST as $name => $value)` it shows only last form value

Comment: @logan, Updated code? I have updated my answer, and now it has an echo line which will print the names and values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48636/discussion-between-logan-and-majid-fouladpour)

Comment: Hi, I found the problem it is with few objects that are not under the form . i have corrected it. Thanks for your help. I accepted your answer