# Submitting All Filled Fields using php

Tags: php, html, forms

Hi I would like first to state that i am more of a designer than a developer.

i am creating a food list for a restaurant containing 200 different food types.

below the HTML:

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="send.php">
<table class="hoverTable" width="300">


<tr><td><strong>CANAPES</strong></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200" >email</td><td><input name="email"type="text"  style="width:200px;"  placeholder="Qty"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200" >Caviar:Black & red</td><td><input name="Caviar"type="text" style="width:50px;" placeholder="Qty"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200" >Cheese & Ham</td><td><input name="Cheese_Ham" type="text" style="width:50px;" placeholder="Qty"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200" >Fetta</td><td><input name="Fetta"type="text"  style="width:50px;" placeholder="Qty"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200" >Goat & Cheese</td><td><input name="Goat_Cheese" type="text"  style="width:50px;" placeholder="Qty"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200" >Halloumi</td><td><input name="Halloumi"type="text" style="width:50px;" placeholder="Qty"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200" >Labneh & Cucumber</td><td><input name="Labneh_Cucumber" type="text"  style="width:50px;" placeholder="Qty"/></td></tr>
<tr><td width="200" >Pepper & Pate</td><td><input name="Pepper_Pate" type="text"  style="width:50px;" placeholder="Qty"/></td></tr>

</table>
<div class="submit"><input type="submit" ID="submit" value="SUBMIT" ></div>
<input type="reset" value="RESET" ID="reset" >
```

and the list continues to contain the 200 names.

i Tried to create the following php form from stuff i collected from the internet:

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

 $email_to = "email@gmail.com";

 $email_subject = "food";


 foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
 if($Value != ''){
 $body .= "$Field: $Value\n";



 @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
 ?>


 Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

 <?php
 }
 die();
 ?>
```

But things doesn't seem to work..

Thank you a lot for the help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreach value from POST from form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479999/foreach-value-from-post-from-form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.  You didn't close out your foreach loop or your check to see if the value has data.  Also, your mail function wasn't using the `$body` variable that you had assigned above and had an extra headers variable in it.

I also cleaned up the code a little to indent it for better readability.

** note ** You can add $headers to format the message as HTML or set your from address if you wanted, but if it's just going to you, I don't think it's necessary.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "email@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "food";

    foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
        if($Value != ''){
            $body .= "$Field: $Value\n";
        }
    }

    mail($email_to, $email_subject, $body);  

    echo "Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you @OrganizedChaos for the reply:)
you fixed my error thank you again

Answer (score 0):

try this now

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

 $email_to = "email@gmail.com";

 $email_subject = "food";


 foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
 if($Value != ''){
 $body .= "$Field: $Value\n";



 @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
 ?>


 Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

 <?php
 }
 }
 }

 ?>
```

The braces were not matching

Comment: Thank you @user7282 for the respond..
but i have one issue

for each field i fill i receive an empty email without any body text or the name of the field.

like if i fill 5 fields i receive 5 empty emails
Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $email_to = "email@gmail.com";

        $email_subject = "food";


        foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value) { 
           if($Value != ''){
               $body .= "$Field: $Value" . "<br>";
           }

        }

        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
    }

 ?>
 Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
```