# Loop $_POST variables with multiple similar names

Tags: php, post, pdo

```
<input name="name_for_the_items[]"/>
foreach($_POST['name_for_the_items'] as $item)
{
  //do something with $item
}
```

This is the code that I got from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479999/foreach-value-from-post-from-form#). It's working for 1 `HTML input`. What I want to do is I got 4 more inputs that need to be loop through. How can I do it with similar code as given above?

btw  i tried

```
<input name="id[]"/>
<input name="time[]"/>
<input name="day[]"/>
<input name="room[]"/>
foreach($_POST['id'] as $item1) {
  foreach($_POST['time'] as $item2) {
     ....
  }
}
```

but it triples or more the data's. Please help.

Comment: Please be more precise in your question. What is the exact html markup that defines those "inputs"?

Comment: @arkascha see i update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something like that:

HTML markup:

```
<form>
  <input name="aspect[id][]"/>
  <input name="aspect[time][]"/>
  <input name="aspect[day][]"/>
  <input name="aspect[room][]"/>
</form>
```

Processing PHP code:

```
<?php
foreach($_POST['aspect'] as $key => $values) {
    foreach($values as $index => $value) {
        // do something with $key, $index and $value
    }
}
```

And a general remark: do yourself a *big* favor and keep the code that creates/defines the form in a separate file from the code that processes the form. I do know that most beginners tutorials show both things mixed together, but that is a very stupid thing to do, actually.

Comment: how can I get the data's from that loop? I tried `$index` but it got me an error `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation`. Sorry I'm new to php

Comment: That would obviously be a issue on SQL level. Did you even bother to read that error message ("SQLSTATE")? That has _nothing_ to do with those loops or form processing in php.

Comment: just tell me how can I get the data's from that loop sir