# How to insert multi text box values into sql using php?

Tags: php, html, sql

```html
<?php 
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fesdb");
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            die();
        }
   if (isset($_POST['Insert'])) 
 {
    $txt = $_POST['text1'];
 }
     
{
$query = "insert into table (Mytext) VALUES ('$txt')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if($result)
            {
               echo '<script>alert("record inserted")</script>';
            }
            else
            {
                echo '  Please Check Your Query ';
             }
         }
?>
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <form action="" id="myForm"  >
            <input type='text' name="text1"><br>
            <input type='text' name="text2"><br>
            <input type='text' name="text3"><br>
            <input type='text' name="text4"><br>
            <input type='text' name="text5"><br>
            <input type='text' name="text6"><br>
            <input type='text' name="text7"><br>
            <input type='text' name="text8"><br>
            <input type='text' name="text9"><br>
            <input type='text' name="text10"><br>
        <input type='submit' name="Insert">
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am a beginner in PHP .. I have sql database with one Table , this table have one column .... I have 10 textboxes in my page with one button ... I want to insert each textbox into the table as separated record ... I know I should use loop (for each ...) to solve this problem ... but I dont know how do that ...
if possible help me with a sample

Comment: So you want to insert each field from the form into a separate row of the table? And where exactly are you stuck? Show the code you've got so far

Comment: Exactly that what I want ... Actually I can't make loop to get textbox value and insert it table as a separated record ..... I don't know how to put my code here in comments

Comment: "Can't" means what exactly? Have you tried _anything_? We're happy to help you here but we do like to see evidence of your own time being spent first. Show us a genuine attempt to write a foreach loop to go through all the POST values

Comment: P.s. don't put code in the comments, it's not designed for that. Your question has an "edit" button, please use that to provide all updates.

Comment: already added code in my post

Comment: Please show your attempt at writing the foreach loop also

Comment: P.s. you forgot `method="post"` in your form tag, otherwise you'll end up with a very messy and possibly too-big url full of text in the querystring when it submits a GET request

Comment: by the way .. I connected my page to sql database successfully ... only the problem is how send text boxes values to table

Comment: Well to put values into the table you need to write an INSERT query

Comment: here is my problem .. how to loop and insert values to Table !!!

Comment: already added php code ... insert query ... but it is only add first text box value

Comment: So, what happens when you try to loop through $_POST with a foreach and run the insert every time? Again, what have you actually tried in relation to that? You seem to know that a loop is needed, so where is your attempt? https://stackoverflow.com/a/5480090/5947043 to get you started